# Good way firebase database structure in order to get those sorted by dates?

Tags: ios, swift, image, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm using firebase and making an app which enables users to save 6 profile images.

Now, I have prepared 6 imageViews and user can simply add their images by tapping each imageViews.

[image]

I want to save the image to firebase Storage and download URL to Firebase Database. Technically, I can save it but I'm not sure how to struct database and name of image files.

Currently, I named image file with Dateformatter(like "yyyy-MM-dd'*'HH:mm:ss".jpg) 
and set download URL to database like 
"yyyy-MM-dd'*'HH:mm:ss" : "downloadURL"

The database structure looks like this:

```
"User" : { 
  “user’s uid” : { 
    "ImgURLs” : { 
      "2018-09-02_21:59:80" : “(here is the url)”, 
      "2018-09-02_22:05:72" : "(here is another url)", 
      "2018-09-02_23:49:54” : "(here is another url)" 
    }, 
  } 
}
```

But in this way, I dont know how to retrieve datas accordingly for those 6 Imageviews.

Is there anyway to implement this if my question makes sense.

Comment: The question kinda makes sense but to provide direction, we should really see how your Firebase is structured, otherwise we may send you the wrong way. Please include a snippet of your your structure as *text* please, no images. You can get that from the Firebase Console->Export JSON. Include that in your question and we'll take a look!

Comment: Hello Jay, thank you for your comment. Heres current DB structure about the photo URL.

Comment: "User" : {
    “user’s uid” : {
      "ImgURLs” : {
        "2018-09-02_21:59:80" : “(here is the url)”,
        "2018-09-02_22:05:72" : "(here is another url)",
        "2018-09-02_23:49:54” : "(here is another url)"
      },
 }
}

Comment: Please include code and structures in your question, not in comments. Comments are for... comments and code is really hard to read without formatting.

Comment: Do you need to store the timestamp as a key or at all? Is there any correlation between the timestamp and order in which the images are shown in the UI?

Comment: Hi, Jay. Thank you for the comment. hmm not precisely! As long as I can sort those images by timestamp. Is there anyway to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A change to how the URL's are stored should provide an answer

```
users :
  uid :
    userName: "some name"
    ImgURLs :
       -Jiokoisd094k //key created with childByAutoId
           url : “(here is the url)”
           timestamp : "2018-09-02_21:59:80"
       -k0k4000od0if //key created with childByAutoId
           url : "(here is another url)"
           timestamp : "2018-09-02_22:05:72"
```

With this, as long as you know the users uid, you can access their image urls at users/uid/ImgURLs. This also allows you to store the timestamp and other information about each image; perhaps a child node of caption: "Dang, you're lookin good" within each child node.

Depending on the use case, if you will need to query those nodes, it may be better to denormalize the data and store them in a separate node

```
users :
   uid :
      userName: "some name"

urls  :
   uid :
      -Jiokoisd094k //key created with childByAutoId
         url : “(here is the url)”
         timestamp : "2018-09-02_21:59:80"
      -k0k4000od0if //key created with childByAutoId
         url : "(here is another url)"
         timestamp : "2018-09-02_22:05:72"
```

Comment: Oh thank you so so much Jay!! Do you have any good idea to retrieve and sort those urls by time by any chance? Thanks anyway again!

Comment: @George Glad it helped! There are a bunch of options for reading those in. Since it's only 6 URL's, I would suggest reading them in all at once via observeSingleEvent by .value, iterate over them to populate an array with the data and sort in code. You could probably just make a structure to keep them in and store those objects in the array.

Comment: Thanks! sorry for another question but to read the datas and get them into the array, which path below would be good? 1.Database.database().reference().child("urls").child(uid) 2.Database.database().reference().child("urls").child(uid).childByAuto

Comment: @George How they are read depends on which of the two structures I proposed. It also depends on how much data is in each child node - and how you read it; via .childAdded (probably not) or .value (how I would do it). For your use case, the first one I suggested seems like it would be fine, so use .observeSingleEvent with .value on the users/uid/ImgURLs node to read the child nodes, and iterate over them to add to an array. Let me know if you need help with that code.

Comment: Thanks! I successfully got datas from database and stored them into an array of tuple! I'm struggling with sorting the each tuples by timestamp but I'll probably ask another question about it! :)

Comment: @George Sorting an array of tuples by the second element (the timestamp) should be something like *myArray.sort { $0.1 < $1.1 }* ensuring that myArray is var, not a let, so it can be sorted in place.

Comment: Oh thank you! I tried this and it worked well! Again, Thank you so much :)